# How to do regular expression (or case insensitive) matching within a mongo aggregation pipeline using $in

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongodb 5.0.7 and would like to perform case insensitive search of string arrays contained within an object using the $in operator in an aggregation pipeline.  I've tried the following

```
use menu
db.dropDatabase()
use menu
db.items.insertMany([
   {
      order : {
         order_id : 1,
         products : [ { item : "item1" }, { item : "item2" } ]
      }
   },
   {
      order : {
         order_id : 2,
         products : [ { item : "Item1" }, { item : "item2" } ]
      }
   }
]);
print("Find all")
db.items.find()

print("\nQuery 0 - Expect 1 item based on case sensitivity")
db.items.aggregate({ $match : { $expr : { $in: [ "item1", "$order.products.item" ] }}}) // works

print("\nQuery 1 - Expect 2 items based on case insensitivity")
db.items.aggregate({ $match : { $expr : { $in: [ /item1/, "$order.products.item" ] }}}) // works

print("\nQuery 2 - Expect 1 item based on case sensitivity")
db.items.aggregate({ $match : { $expr : { $in: [ "item1", { $ifNull : [ '$order.products.item', [] ]  } ] }}} )

print("\nQuery 3 - Expect 2 items based on case insensitivity")
db.items.aggregate({ $match : { $expr : { $in: [ /item1/i, { $ifNull : [ '$order.products.item', [] ]  } ] }}} )

db.dropDatabase()
```

But receive,

```
Find all
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6536c0e6cbf03c71e4b2dbee"), "order" : { "order_id" : 1, "products" : [ { "item" : "item1" }, { "item" : "item2" } ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6536c0e6cbf03c71e4b2dbef"), "order" : { "order_id" : 2, "products" : [ { "item" : "Item1" }, { "item" : "item2" } ] } }

Query 0 - Expect 1 item based on case sensitivity
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6536c0e6cbf03c71e4b2dbee"), "order" : { "order_id" : 1, "products" : [ { "item" : "item1" }, { "item" : "item2" } ] } }

Query 1 - Expect 2 items based on case insensitivity

Query 2 - Expect 1 item based on case sensitivity
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6536c0e6cbf03c71e4b2dbee"), "order" : { "order_id" : 1, "products" : [ { "item" : "item1" }, { "item" : "item2" } ] } }

Query 3 - Expect 2 items based on case insensitivity
{ "ok" : 1 }
bye
```

In the end I need the version that uses $ifNull to work.  Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Why not just use something like `{"$match": {"order.products.item": {"$regex": "(?i)item1"}}}`?

Comment: look https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/schema-design-anti-pattern-case-insensitive-query-index/

Comment: @rickhg12hs because the field may not be present, thus my use of $ifNull above.

Comment: What do you want to happen when `order.products.item` is not present?

Comment: @rickhg12hs For it not to match/select the document.  In particular, $in fails with error if the field is not present.

Comment: Why is my first comment insufficient for your use case?  I don't think you need `"$in"`.

Comment: I suppose I over-simplified the example above.  Ultimately, I want to search for item1 and/or item2? Then I think I need a $expr { $and inside the $match and then regex seems to stop working